# Possibility of working on KDDCup data in local system

Tags: distributed, state-of-the-art

I'm trying to apply classification algorithms to KDD Cup 2012 track2 data using R
http://www.kddcup2012.org/c/kddcup2012-track2

It seems not possible to work with this 10GB training data on my local system with 4GB RAM.
Can anyone work on this data using this kind of a local system ? Or is using a cluster the norm ?
It would be great if anyone could provide me with any guidance on how to get started with working on a cluster and the normally used type of cluster for such tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have, at least, the following **major options** for your *data analysis scenario*:

1. Use *big data-enabling* `R` packages on your **local system**. You can find most of them via the corresponding *CRAN Task View* that I reference in [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/780/2452) (see point #3).
2. Use the same packages on a **public cloud** infrastructure, such as *Amazon Web Services (AWS) EC2*. If your analysis is non-critical and tolerant to potential restarts, consider using *AWS Spot Instances*, as their pricing allows for significant financial savings.
3. Use the above mention **public cloud** option with `R` *standard platform*, but on **more powerful instances** (for example, on AWS you can opt for memory-optimized EC2 instances or general purpose on-demand instances with more memory).

In some cases, it is possible to **tune** a *local system* (or a *cloud on-demand instance*) to enable `R` to work with big(ger) data sets. For some help in this regard, see [my relevant answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/3731/2452).

For both above-mentioned cloud (AWS) options, you can find more convenient to use `R`-focused **pre-built VM images**. See [my relevant answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/4927/2452) for details. You may also find useful [this excellent comprehensive list of big data frameworks](https://github.com/onurakpolat/awesome-bigdata).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I have access to some local systems, can you give me a start on how to set up a cluster using these systems without any cloud services ?
Looks like everywhere AWS is being used.

Comment: @abhivij: You're welcome. Setting up a cluster is not a rocket science, but might be [not trivial](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17923256/2872891), depending on the requirements and your current skills. You can read [this blog post](http://www.smart-stats.org/wiki/parallel-computing-cluster-using-r) and [this blog post](https://beckmw.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/a-brief-foray-into-parallel-processing-with-r) as a starting point. (to be continued)

Comment: @abhivij: (cont'd) Also, you'd have to refer to documentation on multiprocessing `R` packages that you will decide to use, for example [this tutorial](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMPI/vignettes/doMPI.pdf). A more high-level overview and example of an R-based cluster can be found in [this working paper](http://biostats.bepress.com/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1016&context=uwbiostat). Hope this helps.